# Child views of UIPageViewController (SpineLocationMid) have strange frames

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have an IPad project with programmatically implemented UIPageViewController. When I turn device to landscape mode I change pageViewController's spine location to Mid in it's delegate method:

```
-(UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
    ChildViewController *viewController = (ChildViewController *)[self pageControllerAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
    [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
} else {
    ChildViewController *first = (ChildViewController *)[self pageControllerAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
    ChildViewController *second = (ChildViewController *)[self pageControllerAtIndex:currentPageIndex+1];
    [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[first,second] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}
}
```

Then my UIPageViewController displays two pages and it looks fine until I start pagging it. The problem is: one of its child view controller (at the side where I've started flipping) takes all the space of the device screen, so another page becomes hidden below it.
In childViewController's class I found out that in the -(void)viewWillAppear method it is all good with width of the frame (I need it to be 512 - half of my screen), but in -(void)viewDidAppear method it's already 1024.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just setting to my ChildViewController setWantsToFullScreenLayout:NO solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the autoresizing mask or layout constraint of the `ChildViewController.view` and make sure its size isn't affected by parent view size.